Super Cycle Ride Along
I bought a used super Cycle Ride Along but was missing the attachment bracket for the bike.
Where can I buy one, new or used ?
Source:https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/supercycle-ride-a-long-bike-trailer-co-pilot-bike-trailer-20-in-wheels-kids-grey-0715008p.html

Are you in Canada? The product seems to be a branded item for https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/supercycle-ride-a-long-bike-trailer-co-pilot-bike-trailer-20-in-wheels-kids-grey-0715008p.html#nl-product-details.
